# Line chart of all data type string? A timeline?

Tags: google-visualization

I want to make a chart of city council members in my city over time.  I envision this as kind of being like a line chart.  The x axis would be years.  There are nine city council seats, so there would be nine straight lines, and each would show who was city council member over time (perhaps through different colored line segments or by showing their names onMouseOver).  Perhaps this is like a time line.

When I graph the city's budget, since both the years and city budget are type "number," this classic line graph works out nicely.

For this new graph, I am passing all of the data types "string" since they are peoples' names, and Google Charts API is giving the error: "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

How can I make this chart?  (I not only want to graph numeric data like budget surplus or deficit or number of robberies, but relate [in another chart] who was in charge at that time.)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, I queried my mySQL database and produced a JSON object in the format Google Chart API needs to receive to make horizontal lines over time that show names onHover like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("x","y","z");
mysql_select_db("a",$conn);

$sql = "SELECT year,d_mayor,d_council1,d_council2,d_council3 
FROM metrics WHERE year 
IN ('1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012')";

$sth = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

//start the json data in the format Google Chart js/API expects to receive it change
$JSONdata = "{
              \"cols\": [
                 {\"label\":\"Year\",\"type\":\"string\"},
                    {\"label\":\"City Council 1\",\"type\":\"number\"},
                    {\"label\":\"City Council 2\",\"type\":\"number\"},
                    {\"label\":\"City Council 3\",\"type\":\"number\"},
                    {\"label\":\"Mayor\",\"type\":\"number\"}
                  ],
              \"rows\": [";

//loop through the db query result set and put into the chart cell values (note last ojbect in array has "," behind it but its working)
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   $JSONdata .= "{\"c\":[{\"v\": " . $r['year'] . "},  {\"v\": 1, \"f\": \"" . $r['d_council1'] . "\"}, {\"v\": 2, \"f\": \"" . $r['d_council2'] . "\"}, {\"v\": 3, \"f\": \"" . $r['d_council3'] . "\"}, {\"v\": 10, \"f\": \"" . $r['d_mayor'] . "\"},]},";
}    

//end the json data/object literal with the correct syntax
$JSONdata .= "]}";

echo $JSONdata;

mysql_close($conn);
```